# How to make these two buttons centered, one on the right of the other?

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to fix this JS Fiddle so that the buttons are both top (by 10%) and centered, with the second button just to the right of the other button.

http://jsfiddle.net/dopc9x5L/4/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <button class="button1">Play/Pause</button>
    <button class="button2">Reset</button>
</div>

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    
}

.button1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
}
.button2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Currently they are overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
```

As seen [here at jsfiddle.com](http://jsfiddle.net/uh659Lr2/2/)

I set the display style of the wrapper div to flex, and made them centered horizontally by `justify-content: center`. The padding on top is 10% of the wrapper's height.

The `text-align: center` doesn't do anything here, but I kept it in case you want to center the text later on as well.

Comment: Almost, it wasn't exactly at the top of the page on my test website because there are other elements that push it down. That's why I started with position absolute. The following seems to work for me: `.button_wrapper1 {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 20px;
  }

  .button1 {
   position: relative;
   top: 10%;
  }` (same for button 2)

Answer (score 0):

in the style for button1, I put

```
left: 30%;
```

and it worked for me, the play button was behind the reset button.

here's your code:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
    
}

.button1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 30%;
    
}
.button2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```